# Implementation of Alamofire RequestInterceptor with refreshToken

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to handle 401 unauthorized request with Alamofire (5.6.1)

which Alamofire implementation should I use?

At first login post method I'm getting that kind of data:

```
 {
   "authToken": "auth12345",
   "refreshToken": "refresh6789"
 }
```

after that for each request to my API end point (ex. *baseURL* *+* "*/user/api/user-address*")
I'm using that header with **authToken**

```
["Authorization": "Bearer \(authToken)", "Accept": "application/json"]
```

At the moment of expiration of **authToken** I starting to receive 401 code - which is unauthorized request.

To get new **authToken** I have to make request with **refreshToken** to specific endpoint which is:

```
baseURL + /auth/api/refresh-token
```

By reading [alamofire doc](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#adapting-and-retrying-requests-with-requestinterceptor) I'm a bit confusing  which implementation ***RequestInterceptor*** I have to go with:

RequestAdapter, RequestRetrier - says to implement:

```
1. func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest, Error>) -> Void)

2. func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void)
```

but as I see example:

```
func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest, Error>) -> Void) {
    var urlRequest = urlRequest
    urlRequest.headers.add(.authorization(bearerToken: accessToken))

    completion(.success(urlRequest))
}
```

it's just modifies header  (`headers.add`) with same **expired** **accessToken** and not gives you option

to make a call to ***specific endpoint*** with **refreshToken**

There also example of implementation `class OAuthAuthenticator: Authenticator` and

`struct OAuthCredential: AuthenticationCredentia` which is also not visible for me for providing

mechanism for dedicated ***endpoint*** to refresh **authToken** with **refreshToken.**

Answer (score 1):

If you can check whether your token is expired ahead of time, you can implement the refresh in the `adapt` method:

```swift
func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest, Error>) -> Void) {
  // Check token expiration.
  // If expired, call refresh, then call completion.
  // If not expired, adapt the request like normal and call completion.
}
```

If you can't do that, just implement the normal `adapt` you already have and implement the refresh in `retry`:

```swift
func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
  // If error is 401, refresh the tokens, then call the completion handler to trigger retry.
  // Retrying the request should then call adapt with the new token.
  // If the error isn't 401 and you don't want to retry, call completion(.doNotRetry).
}
```

Comment: that is actually correct, each request goes thru adapt method, 
and in case it's not passing validation it's fails into retry, where all work to refresh token should be done. That's works, thank you